# Couchbase select query performance

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have simple SELECT QUERY which takes more than 3 seconds to get the result. Actual result count is 15211

Query:

```
select  meta().id assetId, modelAndPart.partNumberID,assetLocation.id locationId  from ic_v10_mammoet where type = 'asset' and modelAndPart IS NOT null and tenantId='439'
```

EXPLAIN:

```
{
    "requestID": "cda5ed1b-efaf-4c5b-bb67-81f0a3542324",
    "clientContextID": "13583a95-04cc-4722-90dd-9642068f9ea0",
    "signature": "json",
    "results": [
        {
            "plan": {
                "#operator": "Sequence",
                "~children": [
                    {
                        "#operator": "IndexScan",
                        "index": "type_idx",
                        "index_id": "f1d17cd15ab5feb6",
                        "keyspace": "ic_v10_mammoet",
                        "namespace": "default",
                        "spans": [
                            {
                                "Range": {
                                    "High": [
                                        "\"asset\""
                                    ],
                                    "Inclusion": 3,
                                    "Low": [
                                        "\"asset\""
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "using": "gsi"
                    },
                    {
                        "#operator": "Fetch",
                        "keyspace": "ic_v10_mammoet",
                        "namespace": "default"
                    },
                    {
                        "#operator": "Parallel",
                        "~child": {
                            "#operator": "Sequence",
                            "~children": [
                                {
                                    "#operator": "Filter",
                                    "condition": "((((`ic_v10_mammoet`.`type`) = \"asset\") and ((`ic_v10_mammoet`.`modelAndPart`) is not null)) and ((`ic_v10_mammoet`.`tenantId`) = \"439\"))"
                                },
                                {
                                    "#operator": "InitialProject",
                                    "result_terms": [
                                        {
                                            "as": "assetId",
                                            "expr": "(meta(`ic_v10_mammoet`).`id`)"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "expr": "((`ic_v10_mammoet`.`modelAndPart`).`partNumberID`)"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "as": "locationId",
                                            "expr": "((`ic_v10_mammoet`.`assetLocation`).`id`)"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "#operator": "FinalProject"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "select  meta().id assetId, modelAndPart.partNumberID,assetLocation.id locationId  from ic_v10_mammoet where type = 'asset' and modelAndPart IS NOT null and tenantId='439'"
        }
    ],
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "15.0015ms",
        "executionTime": "15.0015ms",
        "resultCount": 1,
        "resultSize": 3009
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you forgot to ask a question. You can use this index.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_assets ON somedata
( tenantId, modelAndPart.partNumberID, assetLocation.id )
WHERE type = 'asset';
```